# Image edges on a blured image using PIL don't blur properly

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

I have a problem while blurring images using the Image.filter(ImageFilter.BLUR) method.

My code:

```
#Open the image from the ImageField
fp_big = open(self.image_big.path, 'rb')
im_big = Image.open(StringIO(fp_big.read()))

#Resize the image
im_big.thumbnail(size_big, Image.ANTIALIAS)

#Blur the image
im_big = im_big.convert('RGB')
for i in range(10):
    im_big = im_big.filter(ImageFilter.BLUR)

#Save the images
temp_handle_big = StringIO()
im_big.save(temp_handle_big, PIL_TYPE)
temp_handle_big.seek(0)

#Save image to a SimpleUploadedFile which can be saved into ImageField
suf_big = SimpleUploadedFile('%s' % os.path.split(self.image_big.name)[-1], temp_handle_big.read(), content_type=IMG_TYPE)

#Delete old images and close fps
fp_big.close()
os.remove(original_path_big)
```

While this code works fine, the result is partially wrong:

[image: Resized image] 
[image: Blurred image]

As you can see, the edges of the image are not properly blurred. Do anyone know why this happens?

Thx in advance.

Comment: I don't know too much about PIL but this could have to do with HOW the image is blurred.  The way I'd blur an image is by splitting it into a matrix of pixels and modifying the value of each in accordance to the pixels surrounding it, or a certain depth of pixels surrounding it or whatever.  Therefore, the bluring might only occur a set depth into the picture pixel wise, or the parts of the image aren't getting blurred because the convolution can't be applied.  Or I'm just talking nonsense.  I dunno. I'm not a doctor.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug in the filtering library. Many filters use a NxN matrix which basically does "any pixel is a combination of itself plus various combinations of the pixels surrounding it"

However, what to do when you reach the edge of the image? It appears that PIL is simply not applying the filter there, since the matrix would overlap the edge and give you invalid results. Probably not noticeable if you just did one iteration, but on 10 iterations... wow!

My suggestion would be to extend the edges of the image on that side by a pixel or two by copying the adjacent pixel colours, applying the filter, then cropping them back out.

Alternately, make the thumbnail bigger than it needs to be, filter, then crop. You'll lose some data that way, but its an easier solution.

Comment: Thanks! I have a the original image (not resized). So what I'm gonna do is what you said. Blur the a copy of the original image and then crop it and resize it. I'll post the code when I'm done! (Can't vote u up yet)

Comment: Not quite what I suggested, but that'll work, since the thumbnailing _after_ blurring will hide the insufficient blurring.